# Are there pictures from a solar eclipse of the earth taken from a moon landing unit or orbiter?

Tags: the-moon, earth, solar-eclipse

Did any moon landing vehicle or orbiter took pictures of a solar eclipse happening on the earth, i.e. the moon's shadow on the earth? (Alternatively from other spacecraft showing the whole globe). A link to those pictures would be nice.

Comment: Do you mean a *total* solar eclipse, i.e. you want to see the Moon's 'shadow' on Earth?

Comment: That's correct, the moon's shadow on the earth.

Comment: Not 100% what you are asking, but USAToday published a photo of the 2017 total eclipse taken from a Southwest airlines flight. You can barely see the curve of the Earth, as well as clearly seeing the shadow both on the moon and cast down on the Earth's surface: [How one photographer captured this breathtaking view of the eclipse from a Southwest flight](https://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/flights/todayinthesky/2018/08/21/2017-solar-eclipse-best-image-southwest-airlines-flight/1050918002/).

Comment: There may be an answer somewhere in [Has the Earth's shadow on the Moon (lunar eclipse) ever been photographed from Space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29900/12102) or in [Have there been any photos taken of a total Earth-Sun eclipse from the Moon, or its vicinity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12116/12102) or in [Has the Moon's shadow on the Earth (solar eclipse umbra) ever been photographed from beyond Earth orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22833/12102) (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) or in [Is this the only eclipse where Moon's shadow on the Earth (umbra) has been photographed by a person in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22376/12102) or in [Have any space stations experienced a total solar eclipse?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22747/12102)

Comment: I think the questioner meant taking a photo from behind the moon when there is a lunar eclipse somewhere on earth. For example, if a moon satellite took a picture exactly lined up to the angle of earth sun at an exact distance at a lunar eclipse, Would there be a halo effect or a ring around the moon? Or just black? Gary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such images are most readily available from full-time Earth-observing satellites.

The [DSCOVR](https://www.nesdis.noaa.gov/content/dscovr-deep-space-climate-observatory) climate observatory sees the Earth from Lagrange point L1, 3.9 lunar distances toward the Sun.
Its EPIC camera captured sequences of images half an hour apart for the solar eclipses of [2016-03-09](https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/?date=2016-03-09) and [2017-08-21](https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/?date=2017-08-21).

Geostationary satellites orbit 0.11 lunar distance from the center of the Earth.
The CIMSS group at Wisconsin has a collection of various weather satellites' [images of several eclipses](http://cimss.ssec.wisc.edu/goes/blog/?s=eclipse).

A lunar point of view would fall between these two examples, qualitatively more like the former than the latter.

Comment: Thanks, impressive photos showing the whole earth globe.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough,  yes-ish.  quoting from a [space.SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12116/have-there-been-any-photos-taken-of-a-total-earth-sun-eclipse-from-the-moon-or) post (pictures there),

> Yes, well, kind of; JAXA's Kaguya (SELENE) took images of the Earth
>   during the February 10, 2009 penumbral lunar eclipse from lunar orbit
>   of roughly 50 km altitude, using its HDTV camera

There have been cases of Earth-orbiting satellites catching images too.  For example, [space.com](https://www.space.com/41489-double-solar-eclipse-satellite-photos-august-2018.html) has an article about the Proba-2 satellite doing so.

Comment: The OP asks about photos of the Moon's shadow on the Earth during a total solar eclipse.